# Backbone router function goto doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm working on an example that I found on codepen. The example is about creating back button functionality. The problem I'm having is when the page loads the App.Router doesn't know about the goto function it says it's Uncaught TypeError: this.goto is not a function. I've gone over the example quite a few times to try and resolve this but I can't seem to get it to work at all. The example is on [codepen](https://codepen.io/LarryAnomie/pen/EjzPjp?editors=1010) and my working example is [here](https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/deZBYN?editors=0010)

My problem is that the router doesn't know about the goto function that I put in there.

Your help would be much appreciated

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {

            window.App = {
                Models: {},
                Views: {},
                Extensions: {},
                Forms: {},
                Controllers: {},
                Router: null,
                linkClicked: false,
                routes: [],
                backDetected : false,
                previousFragment : null,

                init: (route) => {
                    new App.Router();
                    this.instance = new App.Views.App();

                    Backbone.history.start();

                }
            }

            App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                  '': 'home'
                },
                execute: function(callback, args) {
                    var self = this,
                        answer = $.Deferred(),
                        route = Backbone.history.getFragment();

                    if (route === '') {
                        route = 'home';
                    }

                    App.backDetected = false;

                    if (App.routes[App.routes.length - 2] === route && !App.linkClicked) {

                        App.backDetected = true;
                        App.routes.pop();

                        if (App.routes[App.routes.length - 1] === route) {
                            App.routes.pop();
                        }

                    }

                    if (App.routes[App.routes.length - 1] !== route) {
                        App.routes.push(route);
                    }

                    _.delay(function() {
                        // this is super hacky but need a delay as global event on links
                        // takes ages to execute
                        App.linkClicked = false;
                    }, 500);

                    answer.promise().then(function() {

                        App.dirty = false;

                        window.onbeforeunload = null;

                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(self, args);
                        } else {
                            console.log('no callback');
                        }
                    });

                    if (App.dirty) {
                        console.log('app is dirty');

                        window.onbeforeunload = (function(_this) {

                        })(this);

                    } else {
                        answer.resolve();
                    }
                },
                initialize: function(options) {
                    var self = this;
                    this.options = options || {};
                },
                goto: function(view, params) {
                    console.log('goto');
                    console.log(App.instance);
                },
                home: (query) => {
                    console.log('home');
                    let view = new App.Views.Home();
                    this.goto(view); // doesn't work
                }           
            });

            App.Extensions.View = Backbone.View.extend({
                goto: function(view) {
                    console.log('showing view');
                }
            });

            App.Views.App = App.Extensions.View.extend({

            })

            App.Views.Home = App.Extensions.View.extend({

            });

        })();



        $(function() {
          //new App.Router();

          window.App.init();



        }); 
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `home` function is using an arrow function which binds the context of `this`. Thus the `window` object is probably what is getting bound (instead of the router) and `goto` doesn't exist on that. Changing it to a normal function fixes it.

```
home: function(query) {
  console.log('home');
  let view = new App.Views.Home();
  this.goto(view); // doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Could you help me out with one other thing. The App.instance is undefined and I don't know why so how do I get it to equal a view in the goto function

Comment: Doen't worry it was the same mistake I learned something new today about arrow functionality and the this. Thanks heaps

Comment: Glad to help, also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) if you want a deeper understanding of how binding works with arrow functions.